# set_sequential_download() and set_piece_deadline() in libtorrent

Tags: python, p2p, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

i'm working on my project which is to make a streaming client over libtorrent.
i'm using the python client (python binding). 
i searched a lot about these functions **set_sequential_download()** and **set_piece_deadline()** and i couldn't find a good answer on how to force download pieces in order, which means first piece 1 and then 2,3,4 etc..

i saw people are asking this in forums, but none of them got a good answer on the changes need to be done in order it to succeed.

i understood that the **set_sequential_download()** just asks for the pieces in order but in fact they are randomly downloaded. i tried to change the deadline of the pieces using **set_piece_deadline()** , increment each piece but it doesn't work for me at all.

** UPDATE

the goal i'm trying to acomplish , it's downloading one piece at a time so i can make a streaming throgh torrents.

i hope some of you can help me,
thanks Ben.

Answer (score 2):

`set_sequential_download()` will *request* pieces in order. However:

- all peers may not have all pieces. If the next piece you want to download is 3 and one of your peers doesn't have 3 but the next it has is 5, libtorrent will start requesting blocks from piece 5 from that peer.
- peers provide varying upload rates, which means that some peers will satisfy your request sooner than others.

This makes it possible for the pieces to complete out-of-order.

`set_piece_deadline()` is a more flexible way to specify piece priority. It supports arbitrary range requests (as described by Jacob Zelek). Its main feature, though, is that it uses a different approach to requesting blocks. Instead of considering a peer at a time, and asking "what should I request from this peer", it considers a piece at a time, asking "which peer should I request this block from".

This makes it deliberately attempt to make pieces complete in the order of their deadlines. It is still an estimate based on historical download rates from peers, and if the bottleneck for download rates is your own download capacity, it may be very difficult to make predictions of future download rates for peers. A few important things to keep in mind when using the `set_piece_deadline()`` API are:

- It's not important that the deadline is in the future. If the deadline cannot be met given the current download or upload capacity, the pieces will be prioritized in the order they were asked to be completed.
- If a deadline is far out in the future, libtorrent may wait to prioritize it until it believe it needs to request it to make the deadline. If you're streaming a large file, and you know the bit-rate, you can set up deadlines for every piece, and if your capacity is higher than the bitrate, you'll still request some pieces in rarest-first order. Improves swarm quality.
- When streaming data, it's absolutely critical to read-ahead. If you don't set the deadline until you want the piece, you'll always fall behind. There's typically a pretty long round-trip between requesting a piece and completing it. If you don't keep the request pipe full of deadline-pieces, libtorrent will start requesting other pieces again, and you'll get non-prioritized pieces interleaved with your high-priority pieces. You should probably keep a few seconds and at least a few pieces as read-ahead. For video, I would imagine tens of megabytes is appropriate (but experimentation and measurement is the best way to tweak it).

If you are in fact looking to stream video to a player or web browser over HTTP, you may want to take a look at (or use and submit pull requests to):

https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent-webui/blob/master/src/file_downloader.cpp

that's a file-downloader provider that fits into simple http framework in that repository.

**UPDATE:**

If all you want is to guarantee that piece 1 completes before piece 2 (at any cost, specifically very poor performance), you can set the priority of all pieces to 0, except for the one piece you want to download. Once it completes, you'll be notified by an alert and you can set the priority of the next piece you want to 1. And so on.

This will be incredibly slow, since you'll pause the download constantly, and be in constant end-game mode (where you may download the same block from multiple peers, if one is slow). For instance, if you have more peers than there are blocks in one piece, you will leave download bandwidth unused, by not being able to request from all peers.

Comment: hey Arvid , first of all thanks for the help. second , I didn't quite understand what you mean i'm afraid. I don't want to stream over HTTP, (is that what libtorrent does? ) I just want to manipulate the code so the libtorrent would download pieces in order, meaning that piece 2 won't be fully downloaded until piece 1 finished to download.

Comment: you have to understand the distinction between (1) requesting data and (2) receive the last byte of some block of data you requested. libtorrent can only control (1), but it can choose peers cleverly to make it likely that (2) happens in-order. But there's no way of guaranteeing it. The more peers, diverse rates and fluctuation, the less in-order pieces will complete. In order to solve your *actual* problem, you probably need to think about what actually matters and how you can maximize the probability of success. (please update your question to include what you're trying to accomplish)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same problem as you. Setting a torrent to sequential download means the pieces will be downloaded in a somewhat ordered fashion. This may be the intuitive solution for streaming. However, streaming video is more complicated then just downloading all the pieces in order.

Video files come in different containers (e.g. mkv, mp4, avi) and different codes (h264, theora, etc). Some codecs/containers store metadata/headers in different locations in a file. I can't remember off the top of my head but a certain container/codec stores all header information at the end of the file. Such a file may not stream well if downloaded sequentially.

Unless you write the code for determining which pieces are needed to start streaming, you will have to rely on an existing mechanisms. Take for example Peerflix which spawns a browser video player, VLC, of Mplayer. These applications have a good idea of what byte ranges they need for various containers/codecs. When Peerflix launches VLC to play, lets say, an AVI file, VLC will attempt to read the first several bytes and last several bytes (headers).

The genius behind Peerflix is that it tries to serve the video file through it's own web server and therefore knows what byte ranges of the file VLC is seeking. It then determines which pieces the byte ranges fall into and prioritizes those pieces. Peerflix uses some Node.js BitTorrent library, whose exact piece prioritization mechanisms are unknown to me. However, in the case of libtorrent-rasterbar, the set_piece_deadline() function allows you to signal the library to what pieces you need. In my experience, once I determined the pieces needed, I would call set_piece_deadline() with a short deadline (50ms or so) and wait for the arrival. Please note that using set_piece_dealine() is incompatible with sequential downloads (just set them to false).

One thing to note, libtorrent-rasterbar will not write the piece to the hard drive as soon as it gets it. This is a trap I fell into because I tried to read that byte range from the file when the piece arrived. For this you will need to run a thread to catch the alerts that libtorrent-rasterbar passes to your application. More specifically you will receive the raw binary data for that piece in a read_piece_alert.